# How to use CASE alias in WHERE CLAUSE?

Tags: t-sql, case, where-clause, clause

I'm trying to put the "val" into where clause, but it returns error:

```
    Select ff.FormID, ff.FieldID, ff.FieldName, ff.Title, 
    ff.DefaultValue, fv.Value, 
    val = case fv.Value when null then cast(ff.DefaultValue as nvarchar) else fv.Value end,
    ff.DataType from
    (SELECT FormID, FieldID, FieldName, Title, DataType, DefaultValue FROM FormFields where FormID = '766A38D8-8058-42C6-AC46-A18C00D3C1DC' and DEL = 0) as ff
    left join
    (select FormID, FieldID, Value from FormValues where FormID = '766A38D8-8058-42C6-AC46-A18C00D3C1DC' and ItemID = 'FD63CCA2-C95F-4AB4-B84B-A220017027E7' and DEL = 0) as fv
    on ff.FormID = fv.FormID and ff.FieldID = fv.FieldID
where val is not null


Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Invalid column name 'val'.
```

Any kind help is appreciated :)

Comment: If you want to do this you need to use a subquery and place the where clause outside of the subquery or you have to restate your CASE expression in the WHERE.

Comment: You can't refer to the alias there, unless this was a subquery and you were selecting from it. You can instead just use your case statement in `val`'s place in the where clause. It might look messy, but it does the job.

Comment: See "Logical Processing Order of the [SELECT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx) statement". `WHERE` is step 4. and "because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not allowed to use aliases in where clause (in sql server), because the order of logical execution of the query is as follows:

1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP

As you can see `WHERE` clause is being executed before `SELECT`, that's why you cannot refer to aliases from `SELECT` clause

Try:

```
Select ff.FormID, ff.FieldID, ff.FieldName, ff.Title, 
ff.DefaultValue, fv.Value, 
val = case fv.Value when null then cast(ff.DefaultValue as nvarchar) else fv.Value end,
ff.DataType from
(SELECT FormID, FieldID, FieldName, Title, DataType, DefaultValue FROM FormFields where FormID = '766A38D8-8058-42C6-AC46-A18C00D3C1DC' and DEL = 0) as ff
left join
(select FormID, FieldID, Value from FormValues where FormID = '766A38D8-8058-42C6-AC46-A18C00D3C1DC' and ItemID = 'FD63CCA2-C95F-4AB4-B84B-A220017027E7' and DEL = 0) as fv
on ff.FormID = fv.FormID and ff.FieldID = fv.FieldID
where case fv.Value when null then cast(ff.DefaultValue as nvarchar) else fv.Value end is not null
```