# OVER clause. How to order by multiple columns within a CASE clause?

Tags: sql, t-sql

The following SQL code is a sample of larger SQL statement. My question is how can I do `CASE` multiple column `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT ROW_NUMBER()`, similar to the one below comment line. The presented code works, but I need to order by two columns.

I am using MSSQL 2008

```
SELECT TOP(50)
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Total' THEN SUM(TotalViews) ELSE SUM(LastMonthViews) END DESC) AS Position
    ,SUM(Albums.TotalViews) AS TotalViews
    ,SUM(Albums.LastMonthViews) AS LastMonthViews
FROM Albums

--The code to be implemented in the SELECT ROW_NUMBER()
ORDER BY SUM(LastMonthViews) DESC, SUM(TotalViews) DESC
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the desired result?

Comment: I'll try to make and update the question.

Comment: Do you have a `GROUP BY` in the query?

Comment: @ypercube Yes I have, this code is an excerpt from the large query.

Comment: Can you not `ORDER BY LastMonthViews, TotalViews`? Those are the aliases you created for those aggregates; they should be in scope for an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @Mike I think I've tried before. I'm getting
_Column 'Albums.TotalViews' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause._ I canot put this column in GROUP BY because it will break the values down.

Comment: You can't order by Albums.TotalViews. But you *should* be able to order by TotalViews (the alias you gave to `SUM(Albums.TotalViews)`.) If it makes your job easier, change the alias so it's completely different from the columns in any of the tables.. Order by the alias.

Comment: I wonder why `OVER (SUM(LastMonthViews) DESC, SUM(TotalViews) DESC)` is not good enough. How do you want the `ROW_NUMBER()` to act when the `@OrderBy` is not `'Total'`?

Comment: @Mike I was changing alias name and trying to order by the alias name but I was receiving _Invalid column name_ error with the alias name. However got I working. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Mike I have also found that alias cannot be referenced on the same level in the query. It can be used in sub query or CTE.

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3eb4e/1)

Comment: @Mike Sorry I meant in the same level of the select statement, which actually I was trying to do. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906115/how-to-use-case-alias-in-where-clause). From there you can see the ORDER BY is executed after select. There was more related links I have came across.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can repeat the `case` statement in the `row_number()` partitioning clause:

```
SELECT TOP(50)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Total' THEN SUM(LastMonthViews) ELSE SUM(LastMonthViews) END) DESC,
                                    (CASE WHEN @OrderBy = 'Total' THEN SUM(TotalViews) ELSE SUM(LastMonthViews) END) DESC
                          ) AS Position
    ,SUM(Albums.TotalViews) AS TotalViews
    ,SUM(Albums.LastMonthViews) AS LastMonthViews
FROM Albums;
```