# SQL Row_Number reverse order

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I am using SQL Row_Number to get a raking column;

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PolicyRef@ ORDER BY di.Create_date,di.Create_time_hh,di.Create_time_mm) as [Rank]
```

However I need to reverse the order. I've tried adding in Asc but that doesn't seem to make any difference?!

PolicyRef@ is varchar(255), Create_Date is a datetime, but with the time part all as 00.00.00.000, Create_Time_hh is a number (this is the hour in the day the record was created, but stored as 09, 17 etc) and Create_Time_mm is also a number (this is the minut in the day the record was created, but again stored as 19, 57 etc).

Why can I not reorder this in the usual way?

Thanks

Comment: If you want to reverse the order you need to use `DESC`. `ASC` is the default sort order (also: which DBMS are you using?)

Comment: That doesn't seem to change anything either!  How do I find out the DBMS?

Comment: @Becky - DBMS - which specific product are you working with? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:mysql]? Something else? Any question tagged [tag:sql] should, in general, also have a tag for what product you're working with.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008, does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Use "desc" to order descending. Ascending (asc) is the default and will be ordered by ASC if not declared.

Maybe this might be useful? [OVER clause. How to order by multiple columns within a CASE clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858929/over-clause-how-to-order-by-multiple-columns-within-a-case-clause)

You can also order fields by multiple columns, i.e

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3
FROM Table1
Order By Column1 desc, Column2 desc
```

Comment: Ordering by desc doesn't change it, which I don't understand!

Comment: well you have three field whichi one you have desc? one or all three? `ORDER BY di.Create_date DESC, di.Create_time_hh DESC, di.Create_time_mm DESC`

Comment: OH! I didn't realise you needed it for every column, brilliant that's done the trick, thank you so much!