# I would like to perform where clause on the column which has records from multiple columns? Is it possible?

Tags: sql

You can see that I have selected data from three different columns in one column with case and now I want to filter it with where. And I am unable to do that.
If anyone who has the solution could please share. How can I perform where operation on this query?

```
select 
    *,
    case 
       when b.Booking_Status = 'd' then 'Draft'
       when b.Booking_Status = 'r' then 'Reviewed'
       when b.Booking_Status = 'a' then 'Verified'
    end as Status_b,
    case 
       when b.Booking_Status = 'd' then b.Add_By
       when b.Booking_Status = 'r' then b.Review_By
       when b.Booking_Status = 'a' then b.Verify_By
    end as Status_By,
    case 
       when b.Booking_Status = 'd' then b.Add_At
       when b.Booking_Status = 'r' then b.Review_At
       when b.Booking_Status = 'a' then b.Verify_At
    end as Status_Add
from 
    Booking b 
inner join 
    Booked_Units bu on b.Booking_Id = bu.BU_Booking_Id
inner join 
    Enq_Line e on b.Booking_Enqh_Id = e.Enql_Enqh_Id
where 
    Status_Add > GETDATE()
```

Comment: Have you tried `HAVING` instead of  `WHERE`?

Comment: I removed all those dbms tags. Add one of them back!

Comment: please look at this link to improve the question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @ThinkDifferent, that's a very product specific tip!

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Use-Question-Marks#step_1_8

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906115/how-to-use-case-alias-in-where-clause

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combo of and/or:

```
where
(b.Booking_Status = 'd' and  b.Add_At > GETDATE())
or
(b.Booking_Status = 'r' and b.Review_At > GETDATE())
or
(b.Booking_Status = 'a' and b.Verify_At > GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select *
    ,case when b.Booking_Status = 'd' then 'Draft'
            when b.Booking_Status = 'r' then 'Reviewed'
            when b.Booking_Status = 'a' then 'Verified'
    end as Status_b
    ,case when b.Booking_Status = 'd' then b.Add_By
            when b.Booking_Status = 'r' then b.Review_By
            when b.Booking_Status = 'a' then b.Verify_By
    end as Status_By 
    ,case when b.Booking_Status = 'd' then b.Add_At
            when b.Booking_Status = 'r' then b.Review_At
            when b.Booking_Status = 'a' then b.Verify_At
    end as Status_Add
    from Booking b 
    inner join Booked_Units bu on b.Booking_Id = bu.BU_Booking_Id
    inner join Enq_Line e on b.Booking_Enqh_Id = e.Enql_Enqh_Id
    where case when b.Booking_Status = 'd' then b.Add_At
            when b.Booking_Status = 'r' then b.Review_At
            when b.Booking_Status = 'a' then b.Verify_At
    end > GETDATE()
```

or

```
    select * from (
select *
    ,case when b.Booking_Status = 'd' then 'Draft'
            when b.Booking_Status = 'r' then 'Reviewed'
            when b.Booking_Status = 'a' then 'Verified'
    end as Status_b
    ,case when b.Booking_Status = 'd' then b.Add_By
            when b.Booking_Status = 'r' then b.Review_By
            when b.Booking_Status = 'a' then b.Verify_By
    end as Status_By 
    ,case when b.Booking_Status = 'd' then b.Add_At
            when b.Booking_Status = 'r' then b.Review_At
            when b.Booking_Status = 'a' then b.Verify_At
    end as Status_Add
    from Booking b 
    inner join Booked_Units bu on b.Booking_Id = bu.BU_Booking_Id
    inner join Enq_Line e on b.Booking_Enqh_Id = e.Enql_Enqh_Id
    ) as allResults
    where allResults.Status_Add > GETDATE()
```