# sql condition at least one sub items is status success

Tags: mysql, sql

DB structure

example 1 - parent status is `InProgress`

```
Parent -> id: 1 
Children: 
  id: 1 parentId: 1, status: 2 
  id: 2 parentId: 1, status: 1
```

example 2 - parent status is `Completed`

```
Parent -> id: 2 
Children: 
  id: 1 parentId: 2, status: 2 
  id: 2 parentId: 2, status: 2
```

example 3 - parent status is `Pending`

```
Parent -> id: 3 
Children: 
  id: 1 parentId: 3, status: 1 
  id: 2 parentId: 3, status: 1
```

`children` status `1` is `pending`, status `2` is `success`

I want to list all the parent with their `total status` considering all their children like so

```
id   status
1   InProgress
2   Completed
3   Pending
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate the children table per parent ID and see what you've got.

```
select parentId
  case when max(status) = 1 then 'Pending'
       when min(status) = 2 then 'Completed'
                            else 'InProgress'
  end as status
from children
group by parentId
```

Comment: thanks, how do I add a where clause for example `where status in (pending, completed)`

Comment: from here I see using an alias in where is not allowed https://stackoverflow.com/a/20906210/13806459

Comment: found the answer here - https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/204514/216083 `select () as T where status  = "pending"`

Comment: BTw - I think status is reserved so better use `final_status` or something

Answer (score 1):

You can do the trick using the AVG function

```
select av.parentId, 
case when av.avgstatus=1 then 3
     when av.avgstatus=2 then 2
     else 2 
end
from (
 select ch.parentId, avg(ch.status) avgstatus from  children ch group by ch.parentId) av
```

Comment: A good idea. There are two mistakes in your query (alias `c` vs. `ch` and a missing `end` for the `case` expression). And the query be written without a subquery and still remain readable: `select parentId, case avg(status) when 1 then 'Pending' when 2 then 'Completed' else 'InProgress' end as status from children group by parentId`.

Comment: tnx for your remarks, i write it down quickly and i can't test it , say its more conceptual. Now i corrected it. I put there the subquery version for showing the 2 phases, computing and presenting reuslts., of course the direct query may be more confortable